# Why does my Scanner input2 only record the the last input?

Tags: java

I am trying to create a college gpa calculator. The program first asks for the number of classes, the amount of credits for each class, and then for the grade for each class. The program works when the each class has the same amount of credits but does not work when there are different amounts of credits for each class. I have tried debugging the program by including print statements that show the values as the program runs and I have determined that credits only records the last inputted value. Is this just how .nextDouble() works or am I making a mistake? How would I go about fixing this problem? I am also fairly new to Java so if I am making a simple mistake there's a reason why.... Thanks

```
import java.util.*;

public class Calculator {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("This program calculates your college GPA.");
    System.out.println("Enter the number of classes you've taken this quarter/semester:");
    int classes;
    classes = input.nextInt();
    double gradePoint = 0;
    double credits = 0;
    double totalCredits = 0;
    String grades;
    double gpa = 0;
    double total = 0;
    // for loop record number of credits per class
    for (int i = 0; i < classes; i++) {
        Scanner input2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        if (i > 0) {
            // user will be asked this second
            System.out.println("Enter next amount of credit hours:");
        }
        else {
            // user will be asked this first
            System.out.println("Enter the number of credits for each class one by one:");
        }
        credits = input2.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("credits:" + credits);
        totalCredits += credits;
        System.out.println("totalcredits:" + totalCredits);
    }
    System.out.println("credits:" + credits);
    // for loop to record grades input and calculate gpa
    for (int b = 0; b < classes; b++) {
        System.out.println("credits:" + credits);
        Scanner input3 = new Scanner(System.in);
        if (b > 0) {
            System.out.println("Enter your next grade:");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("To receive your GPA, enter your grades one by one:");
        }
        grades = input3.nextLine();
        // if statements will convert letter grades to grade points
        // grade points will then be multiplied by their respective amount of credits
        if (grades.equals("A+")) {
            gradePoint=4.0;
            total += (gradePoint*credits);
        }
        else if (grades.equals("A")) {
            gradePoint=4.0;
            total += (gradePoint*credits);
        }
        else if (grades.equals("A-")) {
            System.out.println("credits:" + credits);
            gradePoint=3.7;
            System.out.println("gradePoint:" + gradePoint);
            total += (gradePoint*credits);
            System.out.println("total:" + total);
        }
        else if (grades.equals("B+")) {
            System.out.println("credits:" + credits);
            gradePoint=3.3;
            System.out.println("gradePoint:" + gradePoint);
            total += (gradePoint*credits);
            System.out.println("total:" + total);
        }
        else if (grades.equals("B")) {
            System.out.println("credits:" + credits);
            gradePoint=3.0;
            System.out.println("gradePoint:" + gradePoint);
            total += (gradePoint*credits);
            System.out.println("total:" + total);
        }
        else if (grades.equals("B-")) {
            System.out.println("credits:" + credits);
            gradePoint=2.7;
            System.out.println("gradePoint:" + gradePoint);
            total += (gradePoint*credits);
            System.out.println("total:" + total);
        }
        else if (grades.equals("C+")) {
            gradePoint=2.3;
            total += (gradePoint*credits);
        }
        else if (grades.equals("C")) {
            gradePoint=2.0;
            total += (gradePoint*credits);
        }
        else if (grades.equals("C-")) {
            gradePoint=1.7;
            total += (gradePoint*credits);
        }
        else if (grades.equals("D+")) {
            gradePoint=1.3;
            total += (gradePoint*credits);
        }
        else if (grades.equals("D")) {
            gradePoint=1.0;
            total += (gradePoint*credits);
        }
        else if (grades.equals("D-")) {
            gradePoint=0.7;
            total += (gradePoint*credits);
        }
        else if (grades.equals("F")) {
            gradePoint=0;
            total += (gradePoint*credits);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Invalid input.");
        }
        // gpa algorithm
        gpa = total/totalCredits;
        System.out.println("totalCredits" + totalCredits);
        System.out.println("gpa:" + gpa);
    }
    System.out.println("GPA: " + gpa);
}
```

}

Also, when inputted:

```
3
5
5
3
A+
B+
C-
```

The program outputs the following:

```
This program calculates your college GPA.
Enter the number of classes you've taken this quarter/semester:
3
Enter the number of credits for each class one by one:
5
credits:5.0
totalcredits:5.0
Enter next amount of credit hours:
5
credits:5.0
totalcredits:10.0
Enter next amount of credit hours:
3
credits:3.0
totalcredits:13.0
credits:3.0
credits:3.0
To receive your GPA, enter your grades one by one:
A+
totalCredits13.0
gpa:0.9230769230769231
credits:3.0
Enter your next grade:
B+
credits:3.0
gradePoint:3.3
total:21.9
totalCredits13.0
gpa:1.6846153846153844
credits:3.0
Enter your next grade:
C-
totalCredits13.0
gpa:2.076923076923077
GPA: 2.076923076923077
```

(the correct gpa should be 3.2)

Comment: Jonas, it would be better if you drill down to the exact problem :) Keep it short and sweet.

Comment: @Jonas Lira I fixed your code the problem in your for loop.

Comment: @Omore is the error in the for loop that involves the Scanner input2?

Comment: no it's logical problem.

Comment: @Omore Could you help me with solving the problem? I'm stuck.

Comment: @JonasLira check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your credits variable, when you input

> - 5
> - 5
> - 3

the last input which is 3 is stored into your credits variable and the same value is going through your 2nd loop which you're using for grades.

**Solution 1:**
Use array credits array and input your all classes credits into this array so that you can access different credits into your grades inputs.

**Solution 2:**
Use only one loop for credits and grades and input one by one I make some code for you.
here is the code.

```
for (int b = 0; b < classes; b++) {
    Scanner input3 = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter credit hours for class :"+(b + 1));
    credits = input2.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("credits:" + credits);
    totalCredits += credits;
    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.println("Enter grade for class : "+(b + 1));
    grades = input3.nextLine();

   }
```

**Inputs:**

```
 3  //number of classes
 5  //first class credits
 A+ //first class grade
 5  .
 B+ .
 3  .
 c- ..........
```

**Output:**

```
gpa:3.2
GPA: 3.2
```

Comment: @JonasLira if this is the right answer mark this answer right. thanks